# deploy to device results in frankenstein binary

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm unsure if this is relevant to my question, but I'll start at the beginning:  In my project I have a view controller which is instantiated dynamically by class name, like this:

```
NSString* className;

...className is set to a valid class name, e.g. "someViewController"

Class c = NSClassFromString( className );
UIViewController* vc = [[c alloc] init];
```

In the current build of the project, `someViewController` is simply a specialized UIViewController.  However, in an **old** build of the project (which was previously deployed to my device), the view controller of type `someViewController` was a specialized `UITableViewController`.

I spent a bunch of time this morning trying to understand why when I ran the build on the device (deploy from XCode), it would crash with an odd call stack and a console message:

```
[someViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xeb62a0
```

With much experimentation I found that if I swapped out the `someViewController` with any other view controller I couldn't repro the problem.  And if I renamed `someViewController` to `someViewController2` I couldn't repro the problem.  The problem was with the symbol name `someViewController`.  Then it dawned on me that `someViewController` **USED** to be a `UITableViewController` and would have had the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` implemented.

In any event; deleting the app off of the device and having XCode deploy a clean copy fixed the issue.

What I want to know is, why?  How?  I guess I've known in the back of my mind for a while that XCode does funky stuff when deploying - I've had issues before where old resources stick around in the deployed bundle after they've been removed from the project.  But I wouldn't have expected there to be issues with Objective-C types.

Answer (score 0):

Simply renaming a .h and .m file and then introducing a new .h and .m with the same name will cause problems. Not to xcode, but to you. Best is to copy files to a directory like /tmp, delete them from the project, later add them to the project as new with a different name.

Comment: clearly.  I want to understand why, and if this issue is documented somewhere.